# Ansible sudo mode depending on variable

Tags: ansible

I am writing an Ansible role to deploy a Docker container to a host. My inventory file contains CoreOS and Ubuntu servers, and Docker has been installed on Ubuntu without allowing its use by non-root users (aka I need `sudo docker ...`). CoreOS hosts don't need it.

I wanted to write a task and use `sudo` only if needed:

```
- name: Start container XX
  sudo: "{{ ansible_os_family and ansible_os_family == 'Debian' }}"
  docker:
    ...
```

Using the `debug` module, I can see this expression returns "True".

Directly using `sudo: "True"` works fine.

But using the given snippet doesn't work, the sudo mode is not enabled.

How can I conditionally use `sudo` to achieve my goal?

Comment: Have you tried to use the `ansible_sudo` variable? Check google, there are bug report about that but it may works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `docker` module itselve but I see one solution for that purpose. You need use conditional `when` with additional parameters in tasks:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
   - name: Debug message
     debug: msg="{{ ansible_os_family and ansible_os_family == 'Debian'  }}"

   - name: Rooted
     shell: service docker restart
     sudo: True
     when: "{{ ansible_os_family and ansible_os_family == 'Debian'  }}|default(false)|bool"

   - name: Not root
     shell: service docker restart
     # This will fail when sudo is needed.
     # When you remove 'not' in condition you will see that
     when: "not {{ ansible_os_family and ansible_os_family == 'Debian'  }}|default(false)|bool"
```

Comment: I don't like duplicating code, especially for this task which is already ~10 lines long (many docker parameters) and exists in two slightly different versions (for two configurations of the container). Double `when` -> 4 times the base code -> meh :/
But thanks for the workaround! :)